# Magick Jack or equivalent on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, voip

I hate to have the Windows PC just for the sake of running my Magick Jack on, Have long since left Windows for Ubuntu for all my home PC's.

Has anyone figured out, how to get this or an alternative working on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagicJack) this is a VoIP solution that doesn't support linux (and apparently it also got lots of criticism about privacy issues).

Maybe you can switch to another VoIP provider indstead?  Most VoIP providers that use SIP (the standard protocol for VoIP) work fine with open source applications used in Ubuntu, and there are also hardware-based SIP solutions.  (And of course there is also Skype.)

Answer (score 0):

According to their ["tech chat"](http://service.liveperson.net/hc/s-61732089/cmd/kbresource/kb-179439830822283869/view_question!PAGETYPE?sq=linux&sf=101113&sg=0&st=814934&documentid=345414&action=view) MagicJack were planning to bring out Linux support in Q1 of this year. Until that happens, tt seems like your best bet is to use a virtual machine running Windows - check out this [mailing list post](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2009-May/183765.html) for details of how somebody else got it working.